# SmtpClient: Недопустимый знак в заголовке электронной почты

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(sendfrom, sendto, subject, body);
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(sendfrom.Split('@')[0], password);
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Метод SmtpClient.Send даёт исключение:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException Сбой при отправке сообщения электронной
>   почты. System.FormatException Недопустимый знак в заголовке электронной почты.

Проблема заключается в наличии русских букв в имени домена. Если изменить имя машины оставив только латинские буквы, всё работает нормально.

Читал (ой не знаю правда ли), это связано с багами в SmtpClient, которые профиксили в более поздних версиях .NET (вроде как начиная с 4.0). Проект под .NET 2.0... Можно исправить как то это дело (естественно, не меняя имя компьютера)? Писать свой SmtpClient желания нет.

Comment: А если записать имя домена в Punycode?

Comment: В имени какого домена? Вы отсылаете почту на русский домен, или у вас имя компьютера с русскими символами?

Comment: Похоже второе: "не меняя имени компьютера" и "имя машины"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если посмотреть исходники, место где отсылается имя компьютера - вот здесь в `SmtpConnection.GetConnection`:

```
this.extensions = EHelloCommand.Send(this, this.client.clientDomain);
```

Нам нужно подменить `clientDomain` поле (оно объявлено `internal`) в `SmtpClient`. `clientDomain` инициируется к конструкторе, значит делаем так:

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient();
SetDomain(smtp);
// делаем дальше нужные вещи
```

Код SetDomain:

```
static void SetDomain(SmtpClient smtp)
{
    var field = typeof(SmtpClient).GetField("clientDomain", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    field.SetValue(smtp, "NonCyrillicDomain");
}
```

Comment: А ну да.. Слышал я про решение проблемы через рефлексию, но не сразу догнал что именно нужно делать. Так в field.SetValue нужно передавать не любое значение, а просто реальное имя домена, в котором только заменены русские буквы на английские типа ИМЯ - IMIA. Или как?

Comment: Нет разницы что туда передавать, smtp сервера игнорируют это значение.